# What is the most efficient way to update table data from other database?

Tags: oracle

I have to create procedure that will be update data in `tableB` but get data from
`tableA` from other database (I am using db-link). My idea is to load `tableA` data to cursor `cursor cur`, create simply loop:

```
for tmp in cur loop
  if tmp.name != (select name from tableB where tableB_ID = tmp.tableA_ID) then
  update tableB set name = tmp.name where tableB_ID = tmp.tableA_ID;
  end if;
end loop;
```

and check each row and each column from two table in search of differences.

This is simple representation of my problem, because I can have around 25 diffrent columns which may need update around 1000 rows. Maybe better solution is to save all differences from one row and create one update statement with many `set`? 
I'm a little confused how to do it efficiently. Create many simple updates (may I need to perform max 25 updates) or create just one complex update. At the end I will add I don't have inforamtion about how many rows have to be updated. Maybe someone have more efficient idea.

Thank for help!

Comment: Could you please specify which databases are you using? (SQL Server, Oracle, etc)

Comment: its a big topic, but one hint if you want to sync changes from one instance to another (and have the know-how to roll your own solution), you'll want to use set operations (select * from tab MINUS select * from tab@somelink).  Also, don't use updates, just do a delete followed by an insert.

Comment: @Av4t4r both databases are Oracle. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to create dynamic statement for each column. Could be similar to this:

```
declare
   sqlstr varchar2(1000);
begin
    for aCol in (select column_Name from user_tab_cols where table_name = 'TABLE_A' and column_name <> 'ID') loop
      sqlstr := 'update tableB b set '||aCol.column_name||
         ' = (select a.'||aCol.column_name||
         ' from tableA a where a.ID = b.ID and '||
         ' a.'||aCol.column_name||' <> b.'||aCol.column_name||')';
     execute immediate sqlstr;
end loop;
```

Comment: You mean, create somethink like this in each if statement, am I understand you correctly ?

Comment: No, this blog will execute 25 update statements and updates entire table